# How do you remove stains from granite?

Tags: cleaning, granite

I've been searching for this answer for probably 5 years. And have yet to get a legitimate answer from anyone.

Is there a method of removing any kind of stain from a granite or granite tile?

I've read about the sprays. I've read about the bleach method. I've read about the baking soda method. Half the people say it works, Half the people say it doesn't.

Is this like a closely kept industry secret? Or is the reality of the situation that there is no, one thing or product or device that can clean granite.

Comment: There's a European company called HG who make a myriad specialist cleaning products. If you can't just pick one up off a DIY store shelf near you, it might be worth contacting their technical dept - see https://hg.eu/uk/products/floors/natural-stone & https://hg.eu/media/zzvkgdzh/uk_natural-stone.pdf

Comment: It's got about the same reviews as the American product by dupont. ~3.5 Stars

Comment: ‘it’ ? They make about 50 different products. Based on the ones I’ve had need to use, reviews from consumers will contain about 50% people who bought the wrong thing, then blamed the product.

Comment: Pretty much across all product lines. The one I've been leaning towards is the 'paste' (oil & grease stain absorber) in a can that you apply to the floor's effected area and let it sit for 48+ hours until it drys and is able to scrap away. But you are correct, most people don't use the product as intended because there really is very little information on the topic. And For some reason, no one on this website wants to share their knowledge either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it. "There is no **one** thing or product or device that can clean granite."

What works, or doesn't, depends on the cause of the stain. Also the preparation of the granite for service, and in some cases "what granite" as there are many different types of "granite" some of which are not even "granite" from a geologist's point of view, and the chemistry of the actual rock (if it's actual rock, not some polymer with rock dust filling) is quite different between types.

Frankly, if the stain has been there for 5 years while you've sought a solution, it's going to be stubborn, and it might just win. Starting your clean-up quickly is generally a good idea.